# How to modify the contents of an .SVG file with Python?

Tags: python, svg, programming-languages

1. I have a .svg file with example contents: `<svg style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.001" /></svg>`
2. I now want to use Python to directly edit the .svg file and change
   `style="fill:#000000;` to my desired color and save it., but I am not sure how to go about this, I have tried a lot of libraries but none do what I
   need.

Comment: you need an XML parser. Maybe ElementTree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: https://pythonexamples.org/python-replace-string-in-file/

```py
#read input file
fin = open("data.svg", "rt")

#read file contents to string
data = fin.read()

#replace all occurrences of the required string
data = data.replace('style="fill:#000000;', 'style="fill:#FF0000;')

#close the input file
fin.close()

#open the input file in write mode
fin = open("data.svg", "wt")

#overrite the input file with the resulting data
fin.write(data)

#close the file
fin.close()
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I wanted, thank you so much.